# jQuery Floating Menu Does not Work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, floating

I have a floating menu plugin I am working on for jQuery and its driving me crazy as it works fine in other browsers but in Chrome it just sits there instead of scrolling the page when the user scrolls up or down:

```
                // Cache :)
            var fblb_cont = $("#fblb_cont");
            var fblb_main = $("#fblb_cont .fblb_main"); 
            var fblb_pos = $('#fblb_cont').position().top;
            var float_easing = "easeOutQuint";

            // When the user scrolls
            $(window).scroll(function () { 


                // Float our bar to correct page location
                // Figure out how much to scroll
                var scroll_factor = $(document).scrollTop();

                // Create our new scrollTo position             
                var newPos = ( fblb_pos + scroll_factor );

                // Check if the window height is within bounds
                if( $(window).height() < $("#fblb_cont").height()+$("#fblb_cont .fblb_main").height() ){

                    // Adjust where needed
                    fblb_cont.css("top", fblb_pos);

                } else {

                    // Otherwise animate our scroll to the new position
                    $("#fblb_cont").stop().animate({top: newPos}, defaults.float_speed, float_easing);

                } // End if



            }); // End on scroll
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#fblb_cont").stop().animate({top: newPos + 'px'},
                          defaults.float_speed, float_easing);
```